# How to Implement a TS Intersection Type With Conflicting Types

Tags: typescript

I'm using a definitely typed library that I'm attempting to create a mocking framework for but I've ran into an issue with an interface that conflicts with itself:

```ts
interface Dictionary<T>{
    [name:string]:T;
}

type ItemCollection<T> = Dictionary<T> & {
    /**
     * Applies an operation to all items in this collection.
     * @param delegate An iterative delegate function
     */
    forEach(delegate: IterativeDelegate<T>): void;
    /**
     * Gets the item using a delegate matching function
     * @param delegate A matching delegate function
     * @returns A T[] whose members have been validated by delegate.
     */
    get(delegate: MatchingDelegate<T>): T[];
    /**
     * Gets the item given by the index.
     * @param itemNumber The item number to get.
     * @returns The T in the itemNumber-th place.
     */
    get(itemNumber: number): T;
    getLength(): number;
};
```

I'm attempting to define a class that implements this types/interface:

```ts
export class ItemCollectionMock<T> implements Xrm.Collection.ItemCollection<T> {
    [index: number]: T;
    [key: string]: T;
    public itemCollection: T[];

    constructor(itemCollection?: T[]) {
        this.itemCollection = itemCollection || [];
    }

    public forEach(delegate: () => void): void {
        this.itemCollection.map(delegate);
    }

    public get(delegate: Xrm.Collection.MatchingDelegate<T>): T[] {
        // ... logic here
    }

    public getLength(): number {
        return this.itemCollection.length;
    }

    public push(item: T): void {
        this.itemCollection.push(item);
    }
}
```

But I get a compile errors since I the functions required to implement the functions defined in the ItemCollection Type, are incompatible with the IDictionary interface.

I can get the code to compile by defining `[key: string]: T` to be `[key: string]: T | any` but that seems wrong...

How should I create a class that implements this type/interface?

### Edit:

[Here is a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Dictionary%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3Astring%5D%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ItemCollection%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Dictionary%3CT%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Gets%20the%20item%20given%20by%20the%20index.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40param%20itemNumber%20The%20item%20number%20to%20get.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%40returns%20The%20T%20in%20the%20itemNumber-th%20place.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(itemNumber%3A%20number)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getLength()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ItemCollectionMock%3CT%3E%20implements%20ItemCollection%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%20version%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Non%20Error%20Version%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7C%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get(itemNumber%3A%20number)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getLength()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) to a TS Playground version of the code that shows the errors and a potent

Comment: What are exact errors you have? Since they aren't incompatible, the only way besides `any` is to make them compatible. What does prevent you from doing that?

Comment: @estus I've added a link to a playgound version of the code to show what's going on...

Comment: You likely have XY problem. `[name:string]` and `[key: string]: T` are obvious problems here, because there are also methods, and they aren't `T`. This means that prop and method names can collide. Numeric props `[index: number]: T` won't be a problem (it's similarly used in Array). String props will.